# Do we really need a steam-big-picture tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

Is [steam-big-picture](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/steam-big-picture) that big of a deal to be distinct from the  [steam](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/steam) tag?  So far there are only 2 questions for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Steam Big Picture is still Steam, so I agree here. No need for the extra tag.